# Как "добавить" SFML в проект?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, разработка-игр, dll, sfml

Я добавил необходимые ссылки на DLL в SFML(первая картинка), и пытаюсь скомпилировать программу, но вылезает ошибка (вторая картинка)

"System.DllNotFoundException: "Не удается загрузить DLL "csfml-graphics-2.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
"

Ну, и я понял, что надо добавить ссылку на другие DLL, которые были в папке с библиотекой(третье картинка). Но, когда я их добавил и нажал на "ОК" вылезает очередная ошибка(четвертая картинка). И как ее решать?
[image: Вторая картинка]
[image: Первая картинка]
[image: Третья картинка]
[image: Четвертая картинка]

Comment: Просто положите все перечисленные библиотеки в папку куда вы собираете проект например `Debug`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fPBAYu8PFs&list=PL4MuWLMiwK6Ymx4h1V_b8lQev35SJkaBM&index=2&t=0s
я подключал по этому уроку, помогло